# Creating a mask with 3 point in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have this 3 points (x,y) and I need to obtain a mask with a triangle where vertices is the points. I should respect some parameters, like the pixel pitch and I need a grid from the minimum x cordinate to the maximum x coordinate (the same for the y).

I tried to do this in matlab with the function poly2mask but the problem is the resultant image: when I have negative coordinates, I cannot see the polygon.

So I tried to center the polygon but I loose the original coordinates and I cannot have they back again because I need to do some elaboration on the image.

How I can obtain a mask triangle from 3 points without modifying the points and respecting the parameters?

Comment: Since your ultimate aim is an image, you will always need co-ordinates that match matrix indices (i.e. positive integers >= 1), so whatever you do you're going to have to shift your co-ordinate system so that all your points are in the upper-right quadrant. Why not just keep track of this shift and apply it in reverse to your points before the "elaboration" stage? And by "points", here, I mean the co-ordinates of your points, not the points themselves - they obviously still must reside within a matrix, whose indices must be positive integers.

Comment: And that is what I do but I need to impose the pixel pitch. For example, I need distance between two near pixel equals to 0.01. How I can do this keeping the relation between the points? Thank you! :)

Comment: Can't you just multiply all the co-ordinates by 0.01? I'm not really sure what you're asking here; perhaps if you included a few lines of code in your question?